# $L^p$ Banach $ \implies L^2$ Hilbert by Jordan-von Neumann Theorem?

Tags: proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The Jordan-von Neumann Theorem states that "If a  normed space satisfies the parallelogram law
$2||x||^2 + 2||y||^2 = ||x + y||^2 + ||x - y||^2$
then we can define a inner product for it by the polarisation identity
$\langle x, y \rangle = 1/4(||x + y||^2 - ||x - y||^2 +i||x + iy||^2 - i||x - iy||^2)$
and this is the unique inner product which induces the original norm $||x|| = \langle x, x \rangle^{1/2}$ ".

So, knowing that $L^2$ is Banach with a norm $||f|| = (\int |f|^2)^{1/2} $ (where $||f||$ is the norm of the equivalence class represented by $f$) can we show that it satisfies the parallelogram law and then construct the inner product ? I think so, but I haven't found a proof of this anywhere so **I would appreciate confirmation or correction of my own proof which follows.**

---

(1) The sum of two (Lebesgue) integrable functions is integrable and the integral of the sum = sum of the integrals.
(2) Re-express the norm: $|f|^2 = ff^*$ (where $f^*$ is the complex conjugate of $f$). So if $|f|^2$ is integrable then so is $ff^*$  and then $||f|| = (\int ff^*)^{1/2} $
(3) **Parallelogram Law:** Consider $||f + g||^2 + ||f - g||^2 $  Since $f, g$ are elements of Banach $L^2$ then so are $f + g, f - g$ and the norms and corresponding integrals exist.
$||f + g||^2 + ||f - g||^2 = \int(f + g)(f + g)^* + \int(f - g)(f - g)^*$
And by (1), $ =  \int(f + g)(f + g)^* + (f - g)(f - g)^*$
Now I can expand and simplify the integrand without worrying if individual terms are integrable knowing that the total remains integrable, and when I do it reduces to $ \int (2ff^* + 2gg^*)$
And since $ff^*, gg^*$ are integrable (being the norms of $f, g$)  then again by (1) $||f + g||^2 + ||f - g||^2 = \int (2ff^* + 2gg^*) = 2\int ff^* + 2\int gg^* = 2||f||^2 + 2||g||^2$
So the parallelogram law is satisfied.
(4) **Polarisation**: by Jordan-von Neumann Theorem, I can now define an inner product
$\langle f, g \rangle = 1/4(||f + g||^2 - ||f - g||^2 +i||f + ig||^2 - i||f - ig||^2)$  where $\langle f, g \rangle$ denotes the inner product of the equivalence classes $[f], [g]$.
Applying linerity of integrals and expansion and simplification of terms which is too tedious to type in here, this expression reduces (not surprisingly) to $\int fg^*$
(5) **Hilbert**: starting from $L^2$ being Banach it now has an inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \int fg^*$ and is therefore a Hilbert space.

Comment: Your proof seems fine but I'm a bit confused as to why you would want to do this instead of just writing down the inner product in the first place? (I'd guess this is why you can't find a version of this proof anywhere)

Comment: @nobody. Thanks for feedback.  I went through the general proof that $L^p$ is Banach so rather than starting with $\int fg^*$ for $L^2$ and proving it satisfies the inner product conditions I thought it might be more elegant to apply the JvN theorem and deduce the inner product - matter of taste perhaps ?

Comment: The reason I don't think this is more elegant is that I'm not sure which of the conditions to be an inner product I wouldn't call obvious for the $L^2$ inner product. In comparison, it seems much more involved to establish the JvN theorem (even if that is really just a computation) and even then one has to do something like your argument which is probably a bit longer than just checking the conditions.